# When the 'Unity Hololens' returns to the game after the home button, a lag occurs

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp, windows-10

I am using Unity 2017.2.0f3-MRTP, and the UWP SDK used version 99.

```
[Player Settings]
Scripting Backed : .NET
Api Compatibility Level : .NET 4.6

[Build Setting]
Target device : Hololens
Build Type : D3D
SDK : 10.0.16299.0
```

I set up the camera of the package installed by https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity, installed it on Windows 10 after build, and started it.

The game works fine, but when you go out using the home button of the motion controller and then load the game again, will while a lot of lag.

This "can not find a boundary." , The symptoms are the same as when the phrase is displayed, and the movement of the headset becomes fixed.

I do not know where the problem is. I want help.

Comment: What is the "home button" on MSFT motion controller? Are you referring to the Windows button?

Comment: yes. home button is windows button.

Comment: From the symptom I would say that the app is pushed in the background and then a new copy is spawn, quite odd.